# Javascript - set input field to 0 when clicked

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I have list of input fields within a form tag

```
<div class="angefragte_stunden_<%= hour.id%>">
<%= h.text_field :angefragte_stunden %>
```

code output =>

```
<div class="angefragte_stunden_458">
<input id="booking_user_458_angefragte_stunden" name="booking_user[458][angefragte_stunden]" size="30" type="text" value="32" />
```

...

I would like that a user can click into a certain input filed and js replaces the value(ex 32) to 0.

tried:

```
$(document).ready ->  
  $(".angefragte_stunden").on "click", ->   
  $(this).val(0)
```

with no success, I a not very experienced in js/ coffee. so help would be great. Thanks

Thansk so far..
It appears a different problem now..
When I submit the form the new value 0 is not saved but the old value. If I type it by hand then 0 is stored..any idea?

Final Result:

```
<%= form_for @hour_user, :url => ..._path, :remote => true, :method => :put do %>
<div class="angefragte_stunden">
<%= h.text_field :angefragte_stunden, :class => "submittable"  %>
```

coffee:

```
$ ->
 $(".submittable").on 'change', ->
  $(this).parents("form:first").submit()
  $(this).effect "highlight", {}, 1500

$ ->
 $(".angefragte_stunden > input").click ->
  $(this).val(0)
  $(this).parents("form:first").submit()
  $(this).effect "highlight", {}, 1500
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to indent out your coffeescript calls. Coffeescript's block syntax is controlled by indentation.

```
$(document).ready ->  
$(".angefragte_stunden").on "click", ->   
$(this).val(0)
```

is equivalent to js

```
$(document).ready(function(){})
$(".angefragte_stunden").on("click",  function(){})
$(this).val(0);
```

you want

```
$(document).ready ->  
  $(".angefragte_stunden").on "click", ->   
    $(this).val(0)
```

which in js is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".angefragte_stunden").on("click",  function(){
    $(this).val(0);
  });
});
```

as epascarello points out, you also need to fix your classes.  If you want to apply multiple classes, put a space between them. `$(".angefragte_stunden")` will match an element with class `angefragte_stunden` but not `angefragte_stunden_458`

Comment: Thanks so far.. It appears a different problem now.. When I submit the form the new value 0 is not saved but the old value. If I type it by hand then 0 is stored..any idea?

Comment: submitting reloads the page. You'll need to have it set at the start if you want to preserve it across page reloads, or do the submit with an ajax call.  Thats outside the scope of something I can really describe in a comment, but google "ajax forms" and you should be able to find plenty of info.

Comment: Hi Ben thanks.. I can see the point...what do you mean by "start"

Comment: when the page loads initially.

Answer (score 0):

You have no element with the class of `angefragte_stunden`

You need to give it the common class if you want to use that selector.

Change

```
<div class="angefragte_stunden_<%= hour.id%>">
```

to

```
<div class="angefragte_stunden angefragte_stunden_<%= hour.id%>">
```

or use a starts with selector `^=` but that is tricky if you start to ad other classes.

Comment: Yeah, no idea, it was a good point.  I only noticed the coffee problems, missed the class issue completely. Upvoted, and update my answer with credit to you.

Comment: Thansk so far.. It appears a different problem now.. When I submit the form the new value 0 is not saved but the old value. If I type it by hand then 0 is stored..any idea?

Comment: up to now I dont understand this voting...what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#booking_user_458_angefragte_stunden').click(function() {
      $(this).val(0);
    });
});
```

Comment: he's using coffeescript, not javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try something like onClick="this.value = 0" inside the input tags?